# Can't add/sum string values in IEnumerable

Tags: entity-framework, linq, highcharts, sum

The ultimate goal is to display a GrandTotal column using Highcharts. The GrandTotal should be the sum of TotalAmount for a given Offer id.  TotalAmount is a string and the values are like $10.00 or 10.00. GrandTotal is an int, but could easily be changed. Here is what I have done so far.

Step 1) Convert the two IEnumerable lists into their ViewModel counterparts. I set GrandTotal to 0 here because I don't know the amount.

```
var offersConvert = offers
               .Select(o => new OfferSummaryViewModel
               {
                   Id = o.Id,
                   Name = o.Name,
                   Created = o.Created,
                   Shares = o.Shares,
                   Redemptions = o.Redemptions,
                   GrandTotal = 0
               })
               .ToList();

            var sharedOffersConvert = sharedOffers
              .Select(s => new SharedOfferViewModel
              {
                  OfferId = s.OfferId,
                  //TotalAmount = s.TotalAmount.Replace("$", string.Empty).Replace(",", string.Empty).Trim()
                  TotalAmount = s.TotalAmount
              })
              //.Where(i => i.TotalAmount != null)
              .ToList();
```

Step 2) Join the two lists on the Id of the Offer.

```
var data = offersConvert
               .Join(sharedOffersConvert,
               o => o.Id,
               s => s.OfferId,
                (o, s) => new { offersConvert = o, sharedOffersConvert = s })
                .Select(o => new
               {
                   Id = o.offersConvert.Id,
                   Created = o.offersConvert.Created,
                   Shares = o.offersConvert.Shares,
                   Redemptions = o.offersConvert.Redemptions,
                   Name = o.offersConvert.Name,
                   OfferId = o.sharedOffersConvert.OfferId,
                   TotalAmount = o.sharedOffersConvert.TotalAmount,
                   //GrandTotal = Convert.ToInt32(o.sharedOffersConvert.TotalAmount.Replace("$", string.Empty).Replace(",", string.Empty).Trim())
                   //GrandTotal = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(o.sharedOffersConvert.TotalAmount, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
               })
                //.Where(o => o.Id == o.OfferId)
               .OrderBy(o => o.Created.Add(offset))
               .ToList();
```

As you can tell, I've tried to remove any dollar signs and commas. I've even tried to trim white space in order to get clean data. I am then trying to convert the strings to int values, so I can sum them. Nothing seems to work. I've even tried .GroupBy and other methods (see below). At least with .GroupBy I can get to the .Sum operator. With the other method I run into issues when I can't convert int into ToList(), so I have to try and convert ToString().

```
.Where(o => o.Id == o.OfferId)
                .GroupBy(g => g.Id)
                .Select(x => new { GrandTotal = x.Sum(o => o.TotalAmount) })
```

ERROR in above: can't convert TotalAmount to decimal

```
.Where(i => i.Id == i.OfferId)
                 .Sum(i => Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(i.TotalAmount, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                 )).ToString()
```

Does anyone know how I can add/sum the string values in TotalAmount to get a GrandTotal per Offer id?

Any help us much appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE: This works, but I really don't understand why and I don't think it is very clean. I really couldn't find many examples where people were joining two lists together and summing one of the columns. This seems pretty common to me, but perhaps it is not.

```
var data = (from o in offersConvert
                       join s in sharedOffersConvert on o.Id equals s.OfferId
                       orderby o.Created.Add(offset)
                       let k = new
                       {
                           Id = o.Id,
                           Name = o.Name,
                           Created = o.Created,
                           Shares = o.Shares,
                           Redemptions = o.Redemptions
                       }
                       group s by k into totals
                       select new
                       {
                           OfferId = totals.Key.Id,
                           Name = totals.Key.Name,
                           Created = totals.Key.Created,
                           Shares = totals.Key.Shares,
                           Id = totals.Key.Id,
                           Redemptions = totals.Key.Redemptions,
                           GrandTotal = totals.Sum((s => s.TotalAmount == null ? Decimal.Zero : Decimal.Parse(s.TotalAmount, NumberStyles.Currency)))
                       })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: I don't see how you can have a `TotalAmount` and a `GrandTotal` in each record make sense.

Comment: TotalAmount is the total for each sharedOffer. GrandTotal is the sum of all the TotalAmounts for a given Offer id.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Decimal.TryParse("$10.00", NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out var res);
```

Or in the context of your LINQ,

```
GrandTotal = Decimal.Parse(o.sharedOffersConvert.TotalAmount, NumberStyles.Currency)
```

if `o.sahredOffersConvert.TotalAmount` may be null,

```
GrandTotal = (o.sharedOffersConvert.TotalAmount ==null) ? Decimal.Zero : Decimal.Parse(o.sharedOffersConvert.TotalAmount, NumberStyles.Currency)
```

Comment: GrandTotal = Decimal.Parse("$10.00", NumberStyles.Currency) works. This leads me to believe that this call (GrandTotal = Decimal.Parse(o.sharedOffersConvert.TotalAmount, NumberStyles.Currency)) is failing because there could be null values. Is there a way to handle the null values?

Comment: OK, it appears that your null method has worked. I'm now trying to work this into James Curran's answer. It looks like I had more than 1 problem here. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still puzzled why everyone lately has this odd fascination with the Lambda syntax.  And that seems to have been only one of several means you've used to make this more complicated than necessary:

```
var data = (from o in offers
       join s in sharedOffers on o.Id equals s.OfferId
       orderby o.Created.Add(offset)
       select new
            {
                Id = o.Id,
                Created = o.Created,
                Shares = o.Shares,
                Redemptions = o.Redemptions,
                Name = o.Name,
                OfferId = o.OfferId,
                TotalAmount = Decimal.Parse(o.TotalAmount, NumberStyles.Currency)
            })
           .ToList();
```

Further, as `offset` seems to be a constant (for the life of this query), adding it to `Created` isn't going to affect the ordering, and that bit can be removed.

And, since it appears your final output is just the grand totals, it can be reduced further to:

```
var data = (from o in offers
       join s in sharedOffers on o.Id equals s.OfferId
       orderby o.Created
       group Decimal.Parse(o.TotalAmount, NumberStyles.Currency) by o.id into totals
       select new
            {
                Id = totals.Key,
                GrandAmount = totals.Sum()
            })
           .ToList();
```

UPDATE: Putting back what I took out... This should work (I don't have your tables, so I can't test it)

```
var data = (from o in offers
        join s in sharedOffers on o.Id equals s.OfferId
        orderby o.Created.Add
        group o by o.Id into totals
        let item = totals.First()
        select new
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Created = item.Created,
            Shares = item.Shares,
            Redemptions = o.Redemptions,
            Name = item.Name,
            OfferId = item.OfferId,
            GrandTotal = totals.Sum(t=>Decimal.Parse(t.TotalAmount, NumberStyles.Currency))
        })
       .ToList();
```

Comment: Both of these methods are failing. I think Decimal.Parse is failing because of null values in TotalAmount. Is there a way to account for this? Also, I do need the Id, Created, Shares, Redemptions, Name and OfferId as well. How do I add these fields to the Select statement whereby you've created a group called totals? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your continued help with this. I just added your latest code snippet and I still can't access the data from sharedOffers using the select statement. I have the red squiggly line under OfferId in item.OfferId and TotalAmount in t.TotalAmount. I also need to use something like this to handle potential null values in TotalAmount. totals.Sum(t => t.TotalAmount == null) ? Decimal.Zero : Decimal.Parse(t => t.TotalAmount, NumberStyles.Currency)